# Adding data to Access database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm playing around with C# and Access databases trying to connect them and insert data through a web to the Access database, however I keep getting this:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll"

on my output console and get nothing else.

not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help will do. Thanks

here's my code for getting the connection:

```
public partial class reg_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    String connString;
    connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite3\test-db1.mdb";

    return new OleDbConnection(connString);

}
```

here's my code for the submit button after user fill the text boxes Name and Surname:

```
protected void submitButtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    String TextBox1 = nameBox.Text;
    String TextBox2 = snameBox.Text;

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
String myQuery = "INSERT  INTO client values ([name], surname) values ('" + nameBox.Text + "','" + snameBox.Text + "');";


OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }





    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `query` statement like below.

```
    myConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
    String myQuery = "INSERT INTO client([name], surname) values ('" + nameBox.Text "','"+ snameBox.Text + "');";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please remove `*` in your statement

Comment: I'm still getting the same error and nothing else. this leaves me clueless :( Have I done my OleDbConnection right? @KaushikMaheta Thank you

Comment: Ah just noticed that removed it but still no change :( @KaushikMaheta Thanks

Comment: I used the parameters but still no change.. i tried removing the exception handler and now I got a "Missing semicolon (;) at the end of sql statement" @KaushikMahata

Comment: nope without the Exception handler I still get " semicolon missing error" and with the Exception Handler I get "First chance exception" thank you so much

Comment: @MoAl-azzaniGawi, are you getting semicolon error compile time or runtime ?

Comment: this will be highlighted " myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();" and get "Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."

Comment: @MoAl-azzaniGawi, See my updated code i have added `;` end of the `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()' statement

Comment: I already had the semicolon in place but now i'm getting a runtime error

Comment: by the way my Page_Load is empty does that affect anything? @KaushikMaheta Thank you

Comment: @MoAl-azzaniGawi, I see your code in which one syntax error as it is. Please remove  `values` in this statement like `INSERT  INTO client ([name], surname)`

Comment: @MoAl-azzaniGawi, Please replace this line in your code `String myQuery = "INSERT INTO client([name], surname) values ('" + nameBox.Text "','"+ snameBox.Text + "');";`